# Retrieving neighbors along a serial chain in Cypher

Tags: cypher

I have a [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xRO7.png) with three types of nodes: `Division` (brown), `Line` (blue), and `Note` (green).

The `Division` is connected to the first `Line` with a directional `PRECEDES` relationship. Each subsequent `Line` is connected to the previous one with another `PRECEDES` relationship. This serial chain is a few hundred nodes long.

This cypher query below will return the `Division` node followed by all the serial `Line` nodes.

```
MATCH (div{id:'some-id')-[:PRECEDES *0..]->(line)
RETURN line
```

I'm new to cypher and I'm struggling to figure out how to also return the green `Note` nodes, which are linked to `Line` nodes via a directional `EXPLAINS` relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the green Notes, you need to add a match that connects to line

```
 MATCH (div{id:'some-id')-[:PRECEDES *0..]->(line)
 Optional MATCH (note:Note) -[:EXPLAINS] -> (line)
 RETURN line, note
```